How to get level of tree we are at in Mud Blazor Mud Tree?
How to Get Level of tree we are at.
Somethng like:-
<MudTreeView Items="_locationsHashSet" SelectedValueChanged="(StudentDto item)=>OnSelectedItemChanged(item)"> </MudtreeView>
void OnSelectedItemChanged(StudentDto node) { } 
but this is giving the data of tree item selected not the Level of tree. How can we achieve this?
